# JS functions work in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have created a function which works fine on Chrome but seems to produce an error on firefox

```
ReferenceError: playNextClip is not defined
```

You can view the site at: http://thewild.com.au/caleboys/

My JS is as follows.

```
 function queueVideos(num, amount) {

    if (num < amount) {
        document.getElementById('video-element-'+num).addEventListener(
            'ended',
            playNextClip,
            false);
        function playNextClip() {
            var nextVid = num + 1;
            $( '#video-element-' + nextVid ).show().get(0).play();
            $( '#video-element-' + num ).hide();
            document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).pause();
            document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).currentTime = 0;
            queueVideos(nextVid, amount)
        }
    }

    if (num == amount) {
        document.getElementById('video-element-'+num).addEventListener(
            'ended',
            playFirst,
            false);
        function playFirst() {
            $( '#video-element-1' ).show().get(0).play();
            $( '#video-element-' + num ).hide();
            document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).pause();
            document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).currentTime = 0;
        }
    }

}

queueVideos(1, 5);
```

Why does this work in Chrome but not in Firefox?
What can I do to make it cross browser compatible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    function queueVideos(num, amount) {
        if (num < amount) {

            function playNextClip() {
                var nextVid = num + 1;
                $( '#video-element-' + nextVid ).show().get(0).play();
                $( '#video-element-' + num ).hide();
                document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).pause();
                document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).currentTime = 0;
                queueVideos(nextVid, amount)
            }
               document.getElementById('video-element-'+num).addEventListener(
                'ended',
                playNextClip,
                false);
        }

        if (num == amount) {

            function playFirst() {
                $( '#video-element-1' ).show().get(0).play();
                $( '#video-element-' + num ).hide();
                document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).pause();
                document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).currentTime = 0;
            }
document.getElementById('video-element-'+num).addEventListener(
                'ended',
                playFirst,
                false);
        }

    }
    queueVideos(1, 5);
```

Try to give the function defination prior to the addeventlistener.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this work in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Because you are writing invalid JavaScript, and unfortunately browsers decided to gracefully handle this in different ways rather than throwing an error.

According to the specification, *function declarations* inside blocks are **invalid**. Chrome decided to treat them as function declarations and hoists them, Firefox treats them more like function expressions.

The solution is to not use function declarations inside blocks. Either declare them outside the block (i.e. before or after the `if` statement in your case), or use function expression. If you use a function expression you have to define it before you reference it.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood scoping in [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) right, then you need to define the function firefox first before invoking it

So try this

```
    function queueVideos(num, amount) {
    function playNextClip() {
                var nextVid = num + 1;
                $( '#video-element-' + nextVid ).show().get(0).play();
                $( '#video-element-' + num ).hide();
                document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).pause();
                document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).currentTime = 0;
                queueVideos(nextVid, amount)
            }
function playFirst() {
                $( '#video-element-1' ).show().get(0).play();
                $( '#video-element-' + num ).hide();
                document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).pause();
                document.getElementById( 'video-element-' + num ).currentTime = 0;
            }
        if (num < amount) {
            document.getElementById('video-element-'+num).addEventListener(
                'ended',
                playNextClip,
                false);

        }

        if (num == amount) {
            document.getElementById('video-element-'+num).addEventListener(
                'ended',
                playFirst,
                false);

        }

    }
```

Comment: I think the issue is actually caused by the nested named functions.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I guess so, but defining those nested functions first before using it should solve the problem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: @MikeyMusch how can num and amount not be defined when these two are passed in the function as arguments? These two nested functions still has to be defined inside the function 'queueVideos' not outside it.

Comment: Sorry I got ahead of myself and confused your response with the first failed solution I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations are usually `hoisted` in javascript. Function declarations refer to declaring functions like:

```
function myFunction(){..body..};
```

Function expressions are not hoisted in javascript, function expressions look like:

```
var myFunction = function(){..body..};
```

By `hoisting` it means, the function declaration and definition will be moved to top of parent function, so you **can use it** before actually defining it in code.

Functions declared inside a condition is handled differently by firefox and webkit(while in non-strict mode). Functions declared as `declaration` is actually treated as `expression` by firefox and prevents hoisting, where as Chrome still hoists the function declaration even when inside the condition.

So it works for you in Chrome as its hoisted, and doesn't work in Firefox as its not hoisted. As a fix you can define the functions before actually using it.